# Texture Region drawing issue with LibGDX

Tags: textures, libgdx

I am currently moving my old slick2d project to libgdx. I have created a custom AnimationExt class that extends Animation to which I added a draw method. The Animation's frames are actually TextureRegion so I draw current frame TextureRegion. Here is the code, it's pretty simple.

```
    public class AnimationExt extends Animation {

    float stateTime=0;
    TextureRegion currentFrame=null;
    boolean isStopped=false;

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch,float x, float y,int originX, int originY, float xscale, float yscale, boolean hMirror, boolean vMirror, float angle, boolean clockwise){
        if(isStopped==false){
            stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            currentFrame=getKeyFrame(stateTime);

        }else{
            currentFrame=getKeyFrame(stateTime);
        }
        batch.draw(currentFrame, x-currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2, y-currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2,currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),currentFrame.getRegionHeight());
        }


    public AnimationExt(float frameDuration,
            Array<? extends TextureRegion> keyFrames, int playType) {
        super(frameDuration, keyFrames, playType);
    }
}
```

This code works well. BUT when I add parameters to the batch.draw method (originX, originY, scaleX, scaleY, angle, clockwise) like this:

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, x-currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2, y-currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2,originX,originY,currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),xscale,yscale,angle,clockwise);
```

The drawing method goes crazy: it draws the texture rotated to -90 (whereas the angle I entered was 0) and it the width and height are inverted. To fix this I had to do change the code like that :

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, x+currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2, y-currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2,originX,originY,currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),xscale,yscale,90+angle,clockwise);
```

But I don't want to keep this code as I'm pretty sure it's weird and I want to know why does the drawing method have such a weird behaviour when adding more parameters.
By the way, I'm using the very last nightly builds of 17th June.

Answer (score 1):

What values are you using for originX, originY, scaleX, scaleY?
maybe you are using wrong values for originX and originY. The origin is bottom left corner of the textureregion as stated in the docs. To set the origin to the center of the texture set

```
originX = currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2; 
originY = currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2;
```

Hope this helps.

There is also a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564291/how-to-use-spritebatch-draw-method) with a question related to the draw function, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Ups, just saw this was posted a year ago...